# Meaning of "its lead and place" in Kipling's Poem

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, poetry

> THE SAILOR:
>     I tell this tale, which is stricter true,         (25)
>     Just by way of convincing you
>     How very little, since things was made,
>     Things have altered in the shipwright’s trade.
>
> In Blackwall Basin yesterday
>     A China barque re-fitting lay;            (30)
>     When a fat old man with snow-white hair
>     Came up to watch us working there.
>
> Now there wasn’t a knot which the riggers knew
>     But the old man made it---and better too;
>     Nor there wasn’t a sheet, or a lift, or a brace,          (35)
>     But the old man knew its lead and place.

This is a poem by Kipling.

I do not understand what the last line means.

> But the old man knew its lead and place.

What  does  it mean?

I am glad if some one kindly would teach me.

Answer (score 10):

*Place* is not a specifically nautical usage; it's merely the rope's proper location for the function it serves.

*Lead* is a nautical term meaning the rope's direction and the path along which it extends. On a complicated sailing vessel with scores of ropes, making each rope follow a lead which would not interfere with other elements of the rigging could be very tricky matter, involving the careful placement of standard and custom-built tackle.